# Group by foreign Key and get new row

Tags: sql, oracle, having, listagg

I need to count all the foreign keys in the table person and list the `person_id` if the foreign key is referred to more then once. This isn't to complicated if I list all `person_id` in one cell.

For example if I have this table:

```
    PERSON_ID | FOREIGN_KEY
    1           a0368dwas
    2           b65asd14s 
    3           b65asd14s 
    4           a0368dwas
    5           cd56as46a
```

I can do this sql query:

```
    select listagg(person_id), ', '), foreign_key
    from person
    group by foreign_key
    having count(foreign_key)>1
    order by foreign_key
```

the result would be like:

```
    PERSON_ID | FOREIGN_KEY
    1,4         z0368dwas
    2,3         z65asd14s
```

My problem is the user requirement, because he needs the `person_id` not in a single row but a row for each `person_id`.

So it has to be something like this:

```
    PERSON_ID | FOREIGN_KEY
    1           a0368dwas
    4           a0368dwas
    2           b65asd14s 
    3           b65asd14s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where analytic functions (which are sort of similar to aggregate functions, except they don't collapse the rows into a single row) come to the rescue, specifically the `COUNT(*) OVER ()` analytic function:

```
select person,
       foreign_key
from   (select person,
               foreign_key,
               count(*) over (partition by foreign_key) fk_cnt
        from   person)
where  fk_cnt > 1;
```

Here, the "partition by" clause takes the place of the "group by" clause in the aggregate query - it defines the sets of rows the analytic function is going to work over. You have to do the analytic function in a subquery and then filter on the result in an outer query, since there isn't the equivalent of the "having" clause for analytic functions yet.

Answer (score 0):

Select person, foreign_key
From (
Select foreign_key from (Select foreign_key , count(1)
From person 
Group by foreign_key
Having count(1) > 1)
)
Order by 2